# Stem cell research and female egg synthesis

Tags: stem-cells, eggs

In terms of years, how far is stem cell research from being able to produce a female human egg from other female body cells?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that there is no connection between producing egg from somatic cells and stem cell research. The thing that you have mentioned: "produce a female human egg from other female body cells" was already done in 1996 (!) in sheep. Technically, there is no reason that this procedure will not work in Human as well. So in term of years: this was possible 20 years ago ... :-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but when will it be possible to do this for reproductive reasons and get perfect results, unlike with the sheep where lots of defects emerged from the clones/newborn sheep? Thanks.

Comment: This does not answer the question which is about whether egg cells can be produced from somatic cells. What you are describing is SCNT and it is quite a different case.

Comment: I see, so what you are actually asking is about reprogramming cells to become eggs?